# How do I get the objectID after I save an object in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var n = new Chat();
n.name = "chat room";
n.save(function(){
    //console.log(THE OBJECT ID that I just saved);
});
```

I want to console.log the object id of the object I just saved. How do I do that in Mongoose?

Answer (score 126):

This just worked for me:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/lol', function(err) {
    if (err) { console.log(err) }
});

var ChatSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});

mongoose.model('Chat', ChatSchema);

var Chat = mongoose.model('Chat');

var n = new Chat();
n.name = "chat room";
n.save(function(err,room) {
   console.log(room.id);
});

$ node test.js
4e3444818cde747f02000001
$
```

I'm on mongoose 1.7.2 and this works just fine, just ran it again to be sure.

Comment: an undefined room object is indicative of an error saving n. its best practice to perform an error check before accessing the document.

Comment: both n._id and n.id will return the desired result as of mongoose 3.8.21

Comment: @ChrisMcJava your comment was a life saver! When we code many lines and many functions, sometimes we left the error handling later, later could be never or forgotten LOL, Thanks anw!

Comment: Someone did write the answer more succinctly on a later date but I think the extra bit in this answer may be more helpful. For that I give this one the up-vote (8 years down the line, no less).

Answer (score 49):

Mongo sends the complete document as a callbackobject so you can simply get it from there only.

for example

```
n.save(function(err,room){
  var newRoomId = room._id;
  });
```

Answer (score 18):

You can manually generate the _id then you don't have to worry about pulling it back out later.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var myId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();

// then set it manually when you create your object

_id: myId

// then use the variable wherever
```

Comment: Very helpful to know, prevented asynchronous code when synchronous would do.  Thanks!

Comment: That was what I was originally going to do but I think it is unnecessary to be honest. Would answer a different question though.

Comment: You should use `var myId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` to generate an ID. Otherwise you will get the error `TypeError: Class constructor ObjectId cannot be invoked without 'new'`.

Answer (score 12):

You can get the object id in Mongoose right after creating a new object instance without having to save it to the database.

I'm using this code work in mongoose 4. You can try it in other versions.

```
var n = new Chat();
var _id = n._id;
```

or

```
n.save((function (_id) {
  return function () {
    console.log(_id);
    // your save callback code in here
  };
})(n._id));
```

Answer (score 5):

Other answers have mentioned adding a callback, I prefer to use .then()

```
n.name = "chat room";
n.save()
.then(chatRoom => console.log(chatRoom._id));
```

example from [the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html):.

```
var gnr = new Band({
  name: "Guns N' Roses",
  members: ['Axl', 'Slash']
});

var promise = gnr.save();
assert.ok(promise instanceof Promise);

promise.then(function (doc) {
  assert.equal(doc.name, "Guns N' Roses");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I have this:

```
TryThisSchema.post("save", function(next) {
    console.log(this._id);
});
```

Notice the "post" in the first line. With my version of Mongoose, I have no trouble getting the _id value after the data is saved.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the ID should already be there when instantiating the object

```
var n = new Chat();
console.log(n._id) // => 4e7819d26f29f407b0... -> ID is already allocated
```

Check this answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7480248/318380

Answer (score 2):

As per Mongoose v5.x documentation:

> The `save()` method returns a promise. If `save()` succeeds, the
> promise resolves to the document that was saved.

Using that, something like this will also work:

```
let id;
    
n.save().then(savedDoc => {
    id = savedDoc.id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With `save` all you just need to do is:

```js
n.save((err, room) => {
  if (err) return `Error occurred while saving ${err}`;

  const { _id } = room;
  console.log(`New room id: ${_id}`);

  return room;
});
```

Just in case someone is wondering how to get the same result using `create`:

```js
const array = [{ type: 'jelly bean' }, { type: 'snickers' }];

Candy.create(array, (err, candies) => {
  if (err) // ...

  const [jellybean, snickers] = candies;
  const jellybeadId = jellybean._id;
  const snickersId = snickers._id;
  // ...
});
```

[Check out the official doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create)