# Mongoose with mongodb how to return just saved object?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongoose/mongodb

Say I'm saving something:

```
var instance = new TestingModel();
instance.test = 'blah2';
instance.save();
```

So when I save that the instance obj in the db will have, _id and test.  But the _id attribute is added to the object only after entering the db.  Note: I don't want to give it an id before.  However, I want to grab the object in the db because I need to use the _id value, but I don't want to query it again.  Is there a way where you save the object in the database and auto returns the database object so you can get the _id value?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `_id` should be present after saving:

```
var instance = new TestingModel()

instance.test = 'blah'

instance.save(function(err){
    console.log(instance._id) // => 4e7819d26f29f407b0...
})
```

**edit**: actually the `_id` is set on instantiation, so it should already be there before save:

```
var instance = new TestingModel()
console.log(instance._id) // => 4e7819d26f29f407b0...
```

Comment: nice! just tested this.  Hey where is the documentation on stuff like this?

Comment: and do u know of a way to do wat my question asked even tho ur answer does help me?  just wondering...

Comment: I just looked at it again, and it seems the `_id` is generated when creating the object, so just grab it directly from `instance._id`.

Comment: this does not quite answer the question , the question asked for returning the just saved object and not its id

Comment: @NelsonBwogora re-read the question. "and auto returns the database object so you can get the _id value" the poster needed to get the ID for a saved object. The saved object is already there, it's the `instance` var.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to check is the callback of save :

```
instance.save(function(err,savedObj){
    // some error occurs during save
    if(err) throw err;
    // for some reason no saved obj return
    else if(!savedObj) throw new Error("no object found") 
    else console.log(savedObj);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var user = new User();
    user.name = req.body.name;
    user.token = req.body.token;

    user.save(function(err, obj) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json({ message: 'User created!', data: obj });
    });
});
```