# Where to put asserts in asynch mocha testing

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mocha.js

I've seen this https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code regarding how to set-up tests for asynch code. It makes sense, but I am not sure where to put the actual.

So if this is my test:

```
describe('User', function() {
  describe('#save()', function() {
    it('should save without error', function(done) {
      var user = new User('Luna');
      user.save(done);
    });
  });
});
```

Where would I then put something to check the user object's name field or some similar such result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`user.save` returns a callback. Instead of passing in only `done` you you should pass in a function that executes the needed checks and then calls done.

for example:

```
user.save((err) => {
 //do the needed checks on user
 done()
})
```

by the way, the user object that you instantiated, contains both name and id after you called save on it. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479333/mongoose-with-mongodb-how-to-return-just-saved-object?rq=1) for more infos

Comment: That makes sense. My issue now is that instead of getting an assert failure message I get a timeout, but at least it is a failure.

Comment: @Bren, that usually happens when done does not get called, are you sure nothing breaks before getting to done causing it not to get called? also, I doubt it, but it can also be the case that it actually takes a long time to do all you need to don before done is called. In that case look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607039/in-mocha-testing-while-calling-asynchronous-function-how-to-avoid-the-timeout-er

Comment: It results in an unhandled promise, so that is probably to blame. The promise is a few levels lower than what I am testing.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably it then!

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of your code I assume, you're using `Mongoose` or something similar, in which case the callback of the `save()` function has 2 parameters, an `error` and the saved `document`.

```
describe('User', function() {
  describe('#save()', function() {
    it('should save without error', function(done) {
      var user = new User('Luna');
      user.save(function (err, doc) {
        assert.equal(doc.name, 'Luna')
        done()
      });
    });
  });
});
```