# NestJS & Mongoose (MongoDB) - Object creation does not provide _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose, nestjs

I am currently struggling with NestJS in combination with Mongoose.

When I am trying to make a POST request on my nest REST API I get a successful response with all fields I provided. However, I need the _id property in my frontend as well (for navigation purposes).

So the current stored procedure looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class JourneysService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(Journey.name) private journeyModel: Model<JourneyDocument>) {}

  async create(createJourneyDto: CreateJourneyDto): Promise<Journey> {
    const createdJourney = new this.journeyModel(createJourneyDto);
    console.log(createdJourney._id);
    return await createdJourney.save();
  }
  
  [...]
}
```

The result of **console.log(_id)** is null.

The object I get back on a POST request is:

```
return: {
  photos: [],
  active: true,
  _id: null, 
  createdAt: 2021-01-25T20:36:54.809Z,
  updatedAt: 2021-01-25T20:36:54.809Z,
  startDate: null,
  endDate: null,
  title: 'Sample title',
  description: 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
  __v: 0
}
```

Notice the **_id** field containing **null**.

In the database however the **_id** field is set as expected.

When I perform a GET request afterwards the **_id** is also being transmitted:

```
{
        "photos": [],
        "active": true,
        "_id": "600f2be62ef43be2855e358f",
        "createdAt": "2021-01-25T20:36:54.809Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-01-25T20:36:54.809Z",
        "startDate": null,
        "endDate": null,
        "title": "Sample title",
        "description": "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
        "__v": 0
 }
```

So why not on object creation? Does someone know whats wrong? Why is the id field on creation always null?

I have also looked up this question, stating exactly the way I am currently trying to retrieve the _id:
[Mongoose with mongodb how to return just saved object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479333/mongoose-with-mongodb-how-to-return-just-saved-object/7480248#7480248)

Comment: Is it still null after being saved?

Comment: @Joe even after saving it is still null

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6854659/2282634

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are waiting while record creatation that's why _id is not present

```
@Injectable()
export class JourneysService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(Journey.name) private journeyModel: Model<JourneyDocument>) {}

  async create(createJourneyDto: CreateJourneyDto): Promise<Journey> {
    const createdJourney = await new this.journeyModel(createJourneyDto).save();
    console.log(createdJourney._id);
    return createdJourney;
  }
  
  [...]
}
```