# Mongoose - retrieve query result

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I am new in node js and mongoose. I am trying to retrieve user from executed mongoose query on answer on: [stack-overflow-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31738197/how-to-work-with-result-of-the-callback-of-the-find-method-in-a-mongoose-model)

Here is my controller code (it contains both: callback and promises approach)

```
exports.getUser = (req, res, next) => {

    var searchQuery = {...};
    var result = [];
    User.find(searchQuery, function (err, found) {
            console.log(" >>>> inside", found)
            result = found;
        }
    )

    console.log(" >>>> outside ", result)

    var result2 = [];
    User.find(searchQuery)
        .exec()
        .then(function(found){
            console.log(" >>>> inside", found)
            result2 = found
            return found
        }
    )

    console.log(" >>>> outside ", result2)

    res.status(200).json(result)
}
```

In both cases in console it is printing query result inside callback and outside it remains empty, why?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Your code outside of the function is reached before the callback is even executed. Simple asynchronous behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your environment supports async/await, you can also do this:

```
exports.getUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    const searchQuery = {...}
    const result = await User.find(searchQuery)
    res.status(200).json(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really understand what you are trying to do, but your code should look something like:

```
exports.getUser = (req, res, next) => {

    // 1: first query

    var searchQuery = {...};

    User.find(searchQuery, function (err, foundX) {

        // 2: second query

        var searchQuery = {...};

        User.find(searchQuery, function (err, foundY) {

            // 3: send response

            res.status(200).json(foundY);

        });

    });

}
```

You need to wait for the asynchronous code to be executed.

Comment: I wanted to implement such scenario: find X object in db, get from it list of ids referencing to Y objects and finally return list containing X object with Y object list (e.g details).

Comment: Yeah, that was my initial idea :)  Is it possible to achieve it without nesting?

Comment: You could use async / await as proposed by @mtkopone