# Is there a way to log/see if MongoDB .save() is actually working?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a MongoDB connected to Node.js Express, and I have an API controller that accepts POST request and .save() the request body to the database. Yet, even if it console logged the request body correctly and entered inside the .save() method, I checked the terminal with `mongo->db`, but still nothing got created.

Is there a way to determine if MongoDB is actually using the MongoDB .save() method? And also how can I check if the MongoDB is properly connected to the server?

Tried express logging as well:

[image]

And here is how the server is set up:

```
const express = require('express'),
      app = express(),
      logger = require('morgan'),
      config = require('./config/main'),
      mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
      router = require('./router');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(config.database);

const server = app.listen(config.port);
console.log('Your server is running on port ' + config.port + '.');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(logger('dev'));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  next();
})

router(app);
```

And the configuration for the server:

```
module.exports = {
  'database': 'mongodb://localhost/testdatabase',
  'port': process.env.PORT || 3000,
  'secret': 'secretsecret',
}
```

**EDIT 2**

My .save in controller:

```
  user.save(function(err, user) {
      if(err) { return next(err); }

      res.status(201).json({
        user: user
      })
    })
```

**EDIT 3**
Tried logging with `mongoose.set('debug', true);` and got the following:

[image]

Comment: here are some answers : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854431/how-do-i-get-the-objectid-after-i-save-an-object-in-mongoose

Comment: @MilosLulic sorry but can't seem to discern what's what I'm looking for. Can you help

Comment: If using `mongoose`, simply check if `save()` completes or not : `mydoc.save().then(function(d){console.log('SAVED',d);})`

Comment: @S.D. I updated the original post with the .save. Where should the `mydoc.save().then(function(d){console.log('SAVED',d);})` go?

Comment: @JoKo what IDE are you using ? If you are using something like [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/), then you can simply place a break point in callback function and debug the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can set mongoose to debug mode to see whats going on.

```
mongoose.set('debug', true);
```

Comment: sorry but where am I supposed to place it? And what should I be looking for?

Comment: after mongoose.connect is fine. Mongoose will then log everything whats going in and out of mongo

Comment: Thank you Johannes! Just tried it out and update the original post with the screenshot. Does that mean .save() is working? What could be the issue?

Comment: this looks all good to me now. Are you sure nothing is saved in the database?

Comment: i am having same problem; how di you solve it? @JoKo