# How to get the id of a document before even saving it in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I have a simple controller that creates a post for a user. Another schema is linked to it. When I try to create a new post, I need to get the id of the post so that I can link other schema to it.

Here is the schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("./User");
const View = require("./View");

const ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    default: "public",
    enum: ["public", "private"],
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  views: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "View",
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Article", ArticleSchema);
```

It is fine when I want to link the **user** field because I have that stored in memory.

But the **view** field requires postId of that particular document. And I can't get it without first creating the document.

My create post controller:

```js
module.exports.createArticleController = async function (req, res) {
  try {
    req.body.user = req.User._id;
    const article = await Article.create(req.body).exec()
    res.redirect(`/${article.title}/${article._id}`);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};
```

So my question is,

How can i get the id in the process of executing the model.create() so that i can link the view to that id. Maybe something using the ***this*** operator

I don't want to use update after create.

Answer (score 1):

You can get object Id's right after creating an instance of Model or create your own object id's and save them.

Here's how i achieved it:

```js
module.exports.createArticleController = async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const instance = new Article();

    instance.title = req.body.title;
    instance.body = req.body.body;
    instance.status = req.body.status;
    instance.user = req.User._id;
    instance.views = instance._id;

    const article = await instance.save();

    if (article) {
      res.redirect(`/${article.title}/${article._id}`);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};
```

Or you can create them and save it to the db.

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var myId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();

const instance = new YourModel({_id: myId})

//use it
```

Continue reading

[How do I get the object Id in mongoose after saving it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854431/how-do-i-get-the-objectid-after-i-save-an-object-in-mongoose)

[Object Id's format and usage](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/objectid)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your own id and save it

```
ObjectId id = new ObjectId()
```

Comment: Please be more specific about your answer. Add modified code samples and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply create a schema project like this:

```
const task: TaskDocument = new this.taskSchema({ ...createTaskDto })
```

This is from one of my projects since the ObjectId from MongoDB is based on the operating machine and the time it is created. It doesn't need the database to generate the Id.

You can now access `task._id` to get your Id without saving it.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface NotificationModel extends mongoose.Model<NotificationDoc> {
  build(attrs: NotificationAttrs): NotificationDoc;
}

const notificationSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    sk: {
      type: Number,
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Date,
    },
  },
  {
    shardKey: { sk: 1, createdAt: 1 },
    toJSON: {
      transform(doc, ret) {
        ret.id = ret._id;
        delete ret._id;
      },
    },
  }
); 

notificationSchema.statics.build = (attrs: NotificationAttrs) => {
  return new Notification(attrs);
};

const Notification = mongoose.model<NotificationDoc, NotificationModel>(
  'Notification',
  notificationSchema
);

export { Notification };
```

now you can build first then save

````
const notification: NotificationAttrs = {
              sk: user,sk,
              createdAt: new Date(),
            };
const notificationDoc = Notification.build(notification);
console.log(notificationDoc.id)
await notificationDoc.save();
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

no need to save it prior, mongoose does initialize the object model with the objectId

```js
const article = new Article();
console.log(article._id); // <-- this id will be saved to the database
await article.save();
console.log(article._id); // <-- still the same
```